# How do I access post data from scala play?

Tags: scala, playframework

I have a route that is type "POST". I am sending post data to the page. How do I access that post data. For example, in PHP you use $_POST

How do I access the post data in scala and play framework?

Answer (score 10):

As of Play 2.1, there are two ways to get at POST parameters:

1) Declaring the body as form-urlencoded via an Action parser parameter, in which case the request.body is automatically converted into a Map[String, Seq[String]]:

```
def test = Action(parse.tolerantFormUrlEncoded) { request =>
    val paramVal = request.body.get("param").map(_.head)
}
```

2) By calling request.body.asFormUrlEncoded to get the Map[String, Seq[String]]:

```
def test = Action { request =>
    val paramVal = request.body.asFormUrlEncoded.get("param").map(_.head)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here you've got good sample how it's done in Play:

https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/samples/scala/zentasks/app/controllers/Application.scala

```
val loginForm = Form(
  tuple(
    "email" -> text,
    "password" -> text
  ) verifying ("Invalid email or password", result => result match {
    case (email, password) => User.authenticate(email, password).isDefined
  })
)



/**
 * Handle login form submission.
 */
def authenticate = Action { implicit request =>
  loginForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
    formWithErrors => BadRequest(html.login(formWithErrors)),
    user => Redirect(routes.Projects.index).withSession("email" -> user._1)
  )
}
```

It's described in the documentation of the [forms submission](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/ScalaForms)

Answer (score 2):

as @Marcus points out, bindFromRequest is the preferred approach. For simple one-off cases, however, a field

```
<input name="foo" type="text" value="1">
```

can be accessed via post'd form like so

```
val test = Action { implicit request =>
  val maybeFoo = request.body.get("foo") // returns an Option[String]
  maybeFoo map {_.toInt} getOrElse 0
}
```

Comment: `Compilation error[value get is not a member of play.api.mvc.AnyContent]`?

Comment: Try `request.body.asFormUrlEncoded.get("foo").lift(0)` -- I seemed to be getting an `ArrayBuffer` and the `lift(0)` returns an `Option` of the element it contained

Answer (score 0):

Here you've got good sample how it's done in Play 2:

```js
def test = Action(parse.tolerantFormUrlEncoded) { request =>
    val paramVal = request.body.get("param").map(_.head).getorElse("");
}
```