# How do get form post data when not using Play's form pattern

Tags: scala, playframework

I want to create a simple helper function that will return a Option[String] based on the posted form's key.

Currently I am doing this:

```
(request.body.asFormUrlEncoded.get("key1")(0))
```

I want to make a function that returns an Option[String], which I can then cast to Int or Boolean if required.

Comment: Similar question may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11212248/how-do-i-access-post-data-from-scala-play

Answer (score 1):

Accessing `(0)` runs the risk of a `NullPointerException` or `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

How about declaring this method in your controller:

```
def findKey(key:String)(implicit request:Request[AnyContent]):Option[String] = {
  request.body.asFormUrlEncoded.flatMap { form =>
    form.get(key).flatMap { values =>
      values.headOption
    }
  }
}
```

which you can then use quite neatly in your handler function:

```
def workWithFormFields = Action.async { implicit request =>

  val maybeKey1:Option[String] = findKey("key1")
  ...

}
```